# Support for Windows Live Messenger protocol in iChat

Tags: macos, ichat

I Love iChat and its sleek UI and prefer it to Adium or Windows Live Messenger for Mac. iChat now has ".impreferencepane" which allows the addition of support for new networks. My question is: has anybody found a plugin to support Windows Live Messenger within iChat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DrinkBrainJuice is developing a MSN service plug in for iChat (exactly what you're searching): it's called Cocoon and is currently in Public Beta, so give it a try.

http://cocoon.drinkbrainjuice.com/

Comment: Cocoon works ok, but not great, and it appears that the project has been abandoned for some reason. Is anyone else developing a MSN Service plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

Gigaom have a rather convoluted method [here](http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-connect-ichat-to-msn-facebook-and-more/), which involves downloading a program called [Psi](http://psi-im.org/) to act as a Jabber intermediary.

There's allegedly a chat gateway between MSN and Yahoo, which should allow an Yahoo user to talk to MSN users, but I can't find any concrete evidence of it online.

Comment: I have heard of this but i was looking for a more elegant solution using the new plugin support of ichat, adium it is until then lol